# Definition of exterior boundary of compact set

Tags: general-topology, potential-theory

In potential theory, there is a result which states,

> Support of equilibrium measure of compact set belongs to exterior boundary of the compact set.

But what is the definition of exterior boundary of a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\ge 2$. Its complement $U = \mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ is an open set. For sufficiently large $R>0$, the set $V = \{x:|x|>R\}$ is contained in $U$. Since $V$ is connected, there exists a connected component of $U$ that contains $V$. You may want to notice that this is the unique unbounded connected component of $U$.

By definition, the exterior boundary of $K$ is the boundary of the unbounded connected component of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$.

Comment: Isn’t this a standard definition? When I searched for exterior boundary over the Internet it was showing results related to interior, exterior and boundary of set in topological space.

Comment: It's a familiar definition to people familiar with potential theory. If you search with Google, you'll find search results dominated by sources from elementary topology, because there are many more people looking for elementary topology resources than for potential theory resources.

Comment: BTW I was following ‘Potential theory in the complex plane’ by Thomas Ransford in which he has proved above result but never mentioned the definition of exterior boundary. Thanks for the help.